# Dummy Variable Interpretation

Tags: regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding

I'm new to econometrics,but for my university project I have to interpret the results of this equation:

\begin{align}
\ln(bil.export)= b_0 + b_1 \ln(Dist)+ b_2 ln(pop)+b_3 ln(per.cap.GDP)+ b_4(UEcount)+b_5(landlocked)+\ldots+b_{12}(East Asia and Pacific)+ b_{13}(Europe \& Central Asia)+ b_{14}(Latin America \& Caribbean)
\end{align}
Suppose $b_4=0.54$ and $b_5=-0,57$ how should I interpret $b_4$ (UE countries dummy) and $b_5$ (landlocked countries dummy)?

Moving to $b_{12}$,$b_{13}$ and $b_{14}$, how they should be interpreted, considering that another region North America has been excluded from the model?

Comment: Percentage change in $y = 100 \cdot (e^{\beta_k} - 1)$ the number appears to result in some very large changes

Comment: Dummy Variables measure the difference to the reference category (all other independent variables held constant). The reference category is the one that is given when the dummy variable is set 0. Just figure out what your reference category is and apply the interpretation. (As you have a logarithmic dependent variable, the difference should be interpretated as a percentage change of the dependent variable as @repmat mentioned).

Comment: Just to clarify, I can say that being a EU country rather than not being a EU member increases bilateral exports by 71,60% keeping all the other independet variables constant (if the dummy is expressed with 0 for non EU members and 1 for EU members). Am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly. But what I don't understand is why you regression exports on GDP? Exports are a part of GDP no?

Comment: Starting from the gravity model, I found many econometric papers that regress trade flows on distance, population and per capita gdp. In my panel dataset, the correlation coefficient between exports and per capita gdp is moderate, so I thought it couldn't cause any bias. Is it correct? I am sorry for my English but I'm Italian

Comment: Per capita GDP is a proxy for the average income level available for each person living within the specified country/region, and which is included as it could explain the cross-country differences for the demand for export for cars in this model.